# Leer string y números de un archivo y guardarlos en un vector

Tags: c++

Muy buen día a todos!
Espero puedan ayudarme con el siguiente código. Sucede que cuando ejecuto el programa, sólo se ejecuta la primera parte del mismo, es decir, la parte de "Obtener Nombres" y allí se detiene y no ejecuta el siguiente el código restante; pero cuando elimino esa parte o la pongo como comentario usando /* código */, sí se ejecuta la segunda parte del código, la de "Obtener créditos" pero la tercera parte sigue sin ejecutarse. Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias de antemano!
PD: Los archivos que va a abrir en modo de lectura sí están en la carpeta del programa, los puse manualmente para realizar las pruebas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Lectura de archivos";
cout << endl << endl;

//Declarar vectores para cada variable
vector <string> vNombres;
vector <int> vCreditos;
vector <float> vNotas;

//Obtener nombres
string nombre;
ifstream fNombres ("Nombres.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fNombres.is_open()){
    while (getline(fNombres, nombre)){
        vNombres.push_back(nombre);
        cout << nombre << endl;
    }
}
fNombres.close();
//Comprobacion
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    cout << vNombres[i];
    cout << endl;
}

//Obtener creditos
int cre = 0;
ifstream fCreditos ("Creditos.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fCreditos.is_open()){
    while (fCreditos >> cre){
        vCreditos.push_back(cre);
        cout << cre << endl;
    }
}
fCreditos.close();

//Comprobacion
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    cout << vCreditos[j];
    cout << endl;
}

 //Obtener calificaciones
float cal = 0;
ifstream fNotas ("Notas.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fNotas.is_open()){
    while (fNotas >> cre){
        vNotas.push_back(cal);
        cout << cal << endl;
        cin.ignore();
   }
}

//Comprobacion
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
    cout << vCreditos[k];
    cout << endl;
}
fNotas.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que el programa sigue leyendo un archivo infinitamente a pesar de que ya no encuentra más elementos que enviar al vector. No lo sé, es sólo una suposición ya que no le encuentro otra respuesta. Estoy bloqueado :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error de tu código es que en `Obtener calificaciones` estás ingresando lo que lees del archivo en `cre`, pero lo que imprimes es `cal`.
El segundo error es que en la comprobación de las calificaciones estás usando el vector de los créditos, no el de las calificaciones. Además, los vectores tienen una función llamada `size()` que te devuelve el número de elementos que tiene, así que no hay necesidad de poner una constante en el for.
Y el tercer error es poner el `cin.ignore()`, lo único que provocaba era que al imprimir las calificaciones tuvieras que presionar una tecla para que se mostrara cada una de ellas.
Te dejo el código corregido:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Lectura de archivos";
cout << endl << endl;

//Declarar vectores para cada variable
vector <string> vNombres;
vector <int> vCreditos;
vector <float> vNotas;

//Obtener nombres
string nombre;
ifstream fNombres ("Nombres.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fNombres.is_open()){
    while (getline(fNombres, nombre, '\n')){
        vNombres.push_back(nombre);
        cout << nombre << endl;
    }
}
fNombres.close();
//Comprobacion
for (int i = 0; i < vNombres.size(); i++){
    cout << vNombres[i];
    cout << endl;
}

//Obtener creditos
int cre = 0;
ifstream fCreditos ("Creditos.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fCreditos.is_open()){
    while (fCreditos >> cre){
        vCreditos.push_back(cre);
        cout << cre << endl;
    }
}
fCreditos.close();

//Comprobacion
for (int j = 0; j < vCreditos.size(); j++){
    cout << vCreditos[j];
    cout << endl;
}

 //Obtener calificaciones
float cal = 0;
ifstream fNotas ("Notas.txt"); //Apertura del archivo en modo lectura
if(fNotas.is_open()){
    while (fNotas >> cal){
        vNotas.push_back(cal);
        cout << cal << endl;
   }
}

//Comprobacion
for (int k = 0; k < vNotas.size(); k++){
    cout << vNotas[k];
    cout << endl;
}
fNotas.close();

return 0;
}
```

Estos son los archivos que cree para probar:

Nombres.txt

```
Emmanuel
Ernesto
Lopez
Gonzalez
```

Notas.txt

```
10
9
7
8
```

Creditos.txt

```
8
8
6
8
```

Y esta fue la salida:

[image: Salida]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora sí funciona perfectamente pero tengo un par de preguntas:
1. Cuando corregí lo del `cre` y `cal`, el programa siguió sin funcionar, sólo cuando cambié en el `for`el límite superior es que comenzó a funcionar correctamente. El hecho que haya dado un límite número en lugar de usa `vector.size()` afectó en algo?
2. Dentro de las funciones `for` puedo usar la misma variable, cierto? Es decir, en lugar de usa `j` y `k` pude haber seguido usando `i` ya que ésta sólo vive dentro de dicha función. Correcto?
3. Para qué es el `\n`en el `while`?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: 1. Lo que hace el `size()` es asegurarse que se recorra hasta el elemento final del vector, ya que si pones un 3, por ejemplo, si el vector tiene más elementos sólo mostraría los primeros 3, pero si tuviera menos elementos tronaría tu programa por tratar de acceder a una posición fuera del rango del vector.

Comment: 2. Así es, si declaras la variable dentro del `for` limitas su tiempo de vida hasta que termine, así que puedes usarlo afuera otra vez. 3. El `\n` sólo le indica que deje de leer hasta que detecte un salto de línea, generalmente se utiliza para archivos que están guardados con delimitadores y en el caso que te puse el delimitador era el salto, pero creo que la función 'getline()` toma por defecto ese delimitador, así que no es completamente necesario si lees por líneas.

Comment: Entiendo, sucede que el getline no lo usé para obtener los elementos numéricos, tan sólo los string.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Una pregunta adicional, mi función void de impresión me arroja los números con 4 decimales cuando sólo necesito 2 y traté de usar %.2f pero no funciona. Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Ese es para printf en C, si mal no recuerdo. Si estás programando en C++ lo mejor es usar `setprecision()`, te dejo una página con información: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya pude hacerlo funcionar usando `setprecision()`.
Que tenga un buen día!
Bendiciones.